# Can only access all files on svn via tortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

On a linux system using svn 1.8.8 or 1.6.6, I can only access partial files inside a folder on the svn repo.

```
>svn ls http://myserver/svn/directory
>not all files
```

While via tortoisesvn 1.6.16, I see all the files.

I do not know the version of the svn server, nor have the means to obtain it.

Since I do not know the version of the server, it could be a break of compatibility, as stated in [Apache's guide](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/community-guide/releasing.html#release-compat), but I doubt it since tortoisesvn 1.6 works.

tortoisesvn 1.6 release notes mentions [no relevant compatibility concerns](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.6_releasenotes.html).

I do not want to depend on tortoisesvn to access these files, what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the command to list the files recursively:

> svn ls -R http://myserver/svn/directory

and if you want to include more info on each item, you have to specify the verbose flag as well:

> svn ls -R -v http://myserver/svn/directory

But all that can be easily obtained by simply asking the command to show its help info:

> svn help ls

Comment: The problem is that not all files are returned using `svn ls`. Using `-R -v` does not provide more information about the missing files that only show up with tortoisesvn. I can only `svn co` or `svn export` them with tortoisesvn also.

Comment: which files are missing from svn ls -R -v ?